# How to search for a specific column via user input in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist, println

I want to prompt user to search for the 'author' and if yes, display all books written by that particular author. Here's my code so far, see bottom of my code.

Text files are stored as: title - author - publisher - price - pages - isbn

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class AS2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        String text;
        String filename;
        String[] splitText = new String[6]; //use this array to store data when we split a line of text


        // input the file name first
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the file name you want to read data from:");

        filename = keyboard.nextLine();


        try {
            File Fileobject = new File (filename);

            Scanner fileReader  = new Scanner (Fileobject);

            //System.out.println("Title \t Author \t Publisher \t Price \t Pages \t ISBN ");

            while(fileReader.hasNext())
            {
                text = fileReader.nextLine(); //Read a line of data from text file

                // first name and last name are separated by a semicolon
                // Line below separates the content of line of data read by semicolon & store them in the array

                splitText = text.split("-");
                //Check that splitText has 6 elements, if it has fewer then continue with the *next* iteration
                if (splitText.length<6) {
                    System.out.println("Data is missing from this book");
                    //Keep searching and repeat the while loop from the top
                    continue;
                }

                if (splitText[0].trim().length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Title does not exist");
                }
                if (splitText[1].trim().length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("author does not exist");
                }
                if (splitText[2].trim().length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("publisher does not exist");
                } 
                boolean isValidPrice = true;
                try {
                    Double.parseDouble(splitText[3]);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    isValidPrice = false;
                }
                if (!isValidPrice) {
                    System.out.println("Book price may not be a numeric value" + splitText[3]);
                }
                if (splitText[4].trim().length() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Book pages not numerical");
                }   
                if (splitText[5].trim().length() < 10) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid ISBN");
                }

                // Assuming the line of data read from file has first name &  last name 
                // Once the data is split, there should be two items in the array

                // Output  the contents of array elements 
                System.out.println(String.format("%-12s %s", "Title:", splitText[0]) ); 
                System.out.println(String.format("%-12s %s", "Author:", splitText[1]) );
                System.out.println(String.format("%-12s %s", "Publisher:", splitText[2]) );
                System.out.println(String.format("%-12s %s", "Price:", splitText[3]) );
                System.out.println(String.format("%-12s %s", "Pages:", splitText[4]) );
                System.out.println(String.format("%-12s %s", "ISBN:", splitText[5]) );
                System.out.println("------------------------------------" );



            }//End of while loop
            fileReader.close();
        }//End of try 

        catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            //System.out.println("Invalid file name, file does not exist");
        }
        //System.out.println("Do you want to search for an Author?");
        //String answer = input.nextLine();
        // (answer.equals("yes") answer.equals("y")); {
        //  System.out.println("Enter author name");
            //print out all books with that author name (splitText1)


        }
    }
```

Output:

```
:Prompt user to search for Author
        Yes or No
        Enter Authors name
        Print out all books with that authors name
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Your code is reading a single file. Is all the data stored in just one file?

Comment: Yes a single, some elements may be missing or incomplete/incorrect. OOP programming - Graham Winter - O'Reilly - 32.50 - 120 - 0471974555
Windows XP Unwired - Wei Meng Lee - O'Reilly - 12.99 - 94 - 0596005369
CCDA Exam Guide - Anthony Bruno -  Cisco Press - 49.95 - 232 - 0735700745
Multimedia Comms - Fred Halsall -  Addison Wesley - 53.99 - 340 - 0201398184

Answer (score 0):

Store contents of the file in a data structure. This can be done in several ways depending on your needs. For example, you can create a `Book` object containing title, author, publisher, price, pages, and isbn, and store them in an array. You can then do a linear search within that array.